# Tab Bar Controller Blue Overlay

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8, tabbarcontroller

[image: Tab Bar Item]

After xcode update my tab bar controller look like this.
This is 1 item, but all of them looks like this. Blue overlay covers most of the screen making it impossible to do any layout.

Comment: I managed to do layout by removing items form tab bar controller. 
But still, thats not solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can find that works is removing the segue and attaching it when i want to build and run.

Comment: Ye i think we all do same thing, but its really anoying. :)